# The name of my child

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle

I have recently acquired a small child. I need to name them. Actually, I already have. I need you to remember it. But how memorable would it be if I just *told* you the name? Not very. Therefore, I have devised a picture from which you must derive their name!

<sub>disclaimer: none of this intro is real and is just padding</sub>

[image: this is a picture]

There is a definite answer, and I hope you may come to find it. I will release hints if many require it.

Hint:

> The picture is minimal, but everything and its placement is key.

Comment: Is it Grights Redbreast Yellowcacks McMountaineer?

Comment: Use an internet poll to name your child. I nominate the name Standy McMountainface.

Comment: is that the peak Große Seekarspitze?

Comment: @HristoPenov I call it mount clip art.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Matthew 
>  German -> Serman -> Sermon -> Sermon on the Mount

Comment: Is there any visible clue for the second step?

Comment: I think it's just that the words sound similar

Answer (score 17):

The colour implies he's German, and he's standing on top of a mountain.

The German word for "mountaineer" is "bergsteiger", but you've moved the "s" away from the "g".

> His name is Berg Steiger.

Answer (score 7):

Is the answer:

> Snow

So the body of the person on the picture is clearly a German flag. 
Thus, I took the G of the eye to mean Germany.

Here's a map of the area around Germany:

[image: Area around Germany]

As you can see, the nearest country to the right of Germany that begins with an S is Slovakia. In between them (the center of the person) lies the Czech Republic.

We now move to the other part of the picture, the thing the person is standing on.

I took this to signify a mountain of some kind.

Using the help of Google like a real puzzle-solving veteran, I discovered the name of the tallest mountain in the Czech Republic: Sněžka.

Sněžka means snow, hence, my answer.

Comment: Nope. The answer is not snow.

Comment: It' not meant to you, but "you know nothing" ^^

Comment: @Sechiro but then the correct answer would be Jon, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 5):

The answer is:

> Matthew.
> He is the colour of the German flag. So "German."
>  His eyes say G-->S so "Serman", or Sermon.
>  He is on a mountain, so "Sermon on the Mount."
>  The sermon on the mount was delivered by *matthew!*

Comment: Actually, it was delivered by Jesus in the book of Matthew

Comment: So his name should be Jesus?

Comment: @user3571366 if it were, there wouldn't be an accepted answer ;)

Comment: ok sorry, I didn't know that actually!

Answer (score 0):

> **G**ipfel**S**türmer
>
>  Gip•fel•stür•mer
>  **Definition:** Conquerer of a/the peak
>  **Origin:** German